# PHP ADOdb, How to test if query is "insert, update, delete, or drop"?

Tags: php, mysql, adodb-php

MySQL/i's `$db->query('some query')` will return a result set for [successful *`SELECT`*, *`SHOW`*, *`DESCRIBE`* or *`EXPLAIN`*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues), or return `true` for [successful *`INSERT`*, *`UPDATE`*, *`DELETE`*, *`DROP`*, etc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues).

As such, we can easily identify the "type" of query:

```
$result = $db->query('some query that we want to identify');

if($result === false){
    echo 'Error'; exit;
}

if($result === true){

    // query is a successful INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc.

}else{ // else type of $result will be result set

    // query is a successful  SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN 

}
```

How can we do the above using [PHP ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/#docs)?

I'm currently using:

```
$result = $db->Execute('some query');

if($result === false){
    echo 'Error'; exit;
}
if(get_class($result) === 'ADORecordSet_empty'){
    // query is a successful INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc?
}else{
    // query is a successful  SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN ?
}
```

which **seems** to work, but it definitely feels fragile and "working against the API". Is there a better way to do it?

Are there built-in ADOdb functions to do it?

Comment: Could you just do a simple search on the sql string before hand to see which keyword it contains?

Comment: @TobyAllen, That's going to fail in many use cases, e.g. if the table/column name contains that keyword and etc. It'll only work if a full blown MySQL source code interpreter is used, and even so the performance (of string parsing) would be outrageous when compared to what the MySQL API offers (`$result === true`).

Answer (score 0):

[ADOdb returns an empty recordset object](https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb/blob/v5.20.0/adodb.inc.php#L1232) when the underlying API called in the DB-specific driver to execute the query returns `true`.

By default this means an `ADORecordSet_empty` object, but this may be different if custom recordset classes are in use (setting [rsPrefix](https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb/blob/v5.20.0/adodb.inc.php#L481)).

In other words, I don't think there is any other way of achieving what you want; you can make the code more portable by comparing against `$db->rsPrefix . 'empty'` instead of hardcoding `'ADORecordSet_empty'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use affected_rows() method

```
if ($DB->affected_rows() !== 0) {
 //true
}
```

http://devcodepro.com/view/70/1/ADOdb-Check-if-MySQL-query-executed-successfully